# How do I bubble an event from a user control up to window it is contained in?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

I have a user control with a search bar and a search button that I am displaying in a window. On the button click I want the event to bubble up to the window where I can do stuff in the window's code behind. I don't want to put the button click code in the user control code behind. How do I do this?

The xaml for the Window looks like this:

```
<dx:DXWindow
x:Class="Client.Support.AskAQuestionDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
xmlns:libRes="clr-namespace:Shared.Lib.Resources;assembly=Shared.Lib"
xmlns:support="clr-namespace:Client.Support"
xmlns:gui="clr-namespace:Client.GUI;assembly=Client.GUI"
Title="{x:Static libRes:Strings.AskAQuestion}" Loaded="DXWindow_Loaded" 
Height="150" Width="700">

<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <support:ZenForumSearchBar VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

In the code behind for the UserControl I have this code for the Click event

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(e);
    }
```

And in the window that contains the user control I tried to make a handler to handle the event like this

```
    private void ButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        switch (fe.Name)
        {
            case "_knowledgeBaseSearchButton":
                break;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I think I am doing everything completely wrong though. How do I get the event that happens in the UserControl to bubble up to the Window where it got instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Button.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click.aspx) is already bubbling event so you don't need `Button_Click` in your `UserControl`. All you need to do is attach handler in you `Window`, `Grid` or `ViewBox`

```
<Grid Button.Click="ButtonHandler">
```

and in the handler check `e.OriginalSource` instead of `e.Source`

```
var fe = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
```

and it should work